# Unite several maps into List/Array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, groovy

I got flexible count of maps like

```
map1 = [Name1: value1, Name2: value2] 

mapN = [Name1: valueN, Name2: valueN]
```

for 2 maps I can make like this:

```
def map1 = [Name1: value1, Name2: value2] 
def map2 = [Name1: value3, Name2: value4]

def arrayOfMaps = [map1, map2]
```

how to make it for N maps? (count of maps is known)

---

I have collection with N repeating group:

CollectionName: "Collection"
setOfEntries: [
entries group: [
entryName: name1,
entryValue: value1,
entryParam: param1]
...
[entryName: nameN,
entryValue: valueN,
entryParam: paramN]]

I can collect them this way:

def collectMaps = Collection.SetOfEntries[0].clone()

But I need only 2 values from each group and can't take the map as it is. I want to take only entryName and entryValue from each entry to a new map and put it in array of maps

Comment: In what format do you have your N maps? As n separate variables? In some collection? As parsed json? If you give us a bit more context we might be better placed to help you. If you truly have them as variables on the form map1, map2, then you are talking about writing a program to write a program. This is usually not the case though so a bit more context would probably help.

Comment: I have collection with N repeating group: 
CollectionName: "Collection" 
setOfEntries: [
entries group: 
[entry1Name: name1,
entry1Value: value1,
entry1Param: param1]
...[entryNName: nameN,
entryNValue: valueN,
entryNParam: paramN]]

I can collect them this way:  
def collectMaps = Collection.SetOfEntries[0].clone()

But I need only 2 values from each group and can't take the map as it is. I want to take only entryName and entryValue from each entry to a new map and put it in array of maps

Comment: I think you want subMap http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#subMap(java.util.Collection) - but it would really help if you would rewrite your question to your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
def listOfMaps = [
    [Name1: 'value1', Name2: 'value2',  Name3: 'value3',  Name4: 'value4'],
    [Name1: 'value5', Name2: 'value6',  Name3: 'value7',  Name4: 'value8'],
    [Name1: 'value9', Name2: 'value10', Name3: 'value11', Name4: 'value12']
]

def listOfMapsWithSelectedKeys = listOfMaps*.subMap('Name2', 'Name4')

listOfMapsWithSelectedKeys.each { map -> 
  println map
}
```

demonstrates a way to filter out only specific keys from a collection of maps. When executed this prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy

[Name2:value2, Name4:value4]
[Name2:value6, Name4:value8]
[Name2:value10, Name4:value12]

─➤
```